# How can i fix a numberformatexception

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and java programming and I know this error is caused by a number format exception but i don't know how to fix it. But i'm new so i'm sorry that its such a low level question.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        public double x = 0;
        public double y = 0;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //Button
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            //EditText
            EditText nop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            EditText cob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

            x = Double.parseDouble(nop.getText().toString());
            y = Double.parseDouble(cob.getText().toString());

            try{
                x = Double.valueOf(nop.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                x = 0;
            }

            try{
                y = Double.valueOf(cob.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                y = 1;
            }


            //TextView
            final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                     Double z = x / y;
                    tv.setText("Result:" + Double.toString(z));
                }
            });

        }
        }
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
08-20 01:03:42.951  18608-18608/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-20 01:03:43.215  18608-18608/com.elie.billsplitter D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-20 01:03:43.258  18608-18608/com.elie.billsplitter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.elie.billsplitter, PID: 18608
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.elie.billsplitter/com.elie.billsplitter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
            at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
            at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
            at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
            at com.elie.billsplitter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-20 01:03:46.732  18608-18608/com.elie.billsplitter I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 18608 SIG:
```

9

Comment: Which line shows the error ?

Comment: By correctly formatting the number? We would be able to give more and better answers if you provided the actual stacktrace

Comment: Where you get the error ?

Comment: The error is right there in the trace: `""` is not parseable into a number.

Comment: @Keppil But how do i fix that

Comment: @Asm Pass correct double value instead of `""`.

Comment: by adding a numericalv alue in that String. it is trying to parse "" to a number, but "" isn't a numeric value, nor can it be parsed to one. "1" would be parsed to 1, but the compiler doesn't know how to interpret "" as number. Make sure there is a value in that String before trying to parse

Comment: You also have multiple examples on how to handle the exception in the code you provided.

Comment: @Keppil for some reason no matter what i do, it still gives me that error. Do you know how i can fix this?

Comment: @Stultuske So how can put a value into the string?

Comment: myValue = "17"; ... or, easier, just check whether or not there is a value in there before trying to parse it. other options have already been suggested

Answer (score 1):

It happenes because you are trying to get the value of edittext and convert it to double. Problem is that you are trying to fetch empty editext value and convert it to double so it gives you error that invalid double "".

If you want to solve your problem then get the edittext value when you needed and check it for empty.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     if(!nop.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !cob.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                     {
                          x = Double.parseDouble(nop.getText().toString()); //Assign value to x here not after the EditText declaration
                          y = Double.parseDouble(cob.getText().toString()); // Assign value to y here not after the EditText declaration
                          Double z = x / y;
                          tv.setText("Result:" + Double.toString(z));
                     }
                     else
                     { 
                          // Show appropriate message for enter the value
                     }  

                }
            });
```

Comment: how do i make the edittext have something in it without interrupting the user inputing their numbers

Comment: @Asm You can check if editText is empty using `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString()){ // do something}`

Comment: @Raghunandan could you tell me what to do in "do something" because im new to this and i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

```
x = Double.parseDouble(nop.getText().toString());
y = Double.parseDouble(cob.getText().toString());
```

You don't need these two lines outside the try block. You already have them in the try block. Keeping them outside makes it prone to throw an exception.

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
//EditText
EditText nop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
EditText cob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

double x = 0;
double y = 1;
try{
  x = Double.valueOf(nop.getText().toString());
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      }
try{
   y = Double.valueOf(cob.getText().toString());
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrap the parsing codes with the `try-catch` block also.

```
        try{
            x = Double.parseDouble(nop.getText().toString());
            x = Double.valueOf(nop.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            x = 0;
        }

        try{
            y = Double.parseDouble(cob.getText().toString());
            y = Double.valueOf(cob.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            y = 1;
        }
```

Also I am not sure why you need both of these lines.

```
        y = Double.parseDouble(cob.getText().toString());
        y = Double.valueOf(cob.getText().toString());
```

(in the case of x also). As @Uma kanth said you can remove one of them

Comment: No, you don't need both of them. The first line is more than enough.